# YouTube IFrame API on Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

More of an "answer" than a "question", but not having found this elsewhere I'm posting it here.

I was having difficulty initializing the iFrame API in all versions of IE and Firefox, with a somewhat custom implementation. Basically, it would load the API, but wouldn't create the player object.

After a bit of trial and error, I finally figured out it wasn't working because the `div` ID I was passing to the object had its CSS visibility set to `'none'`. Once it was set to `'visible'` the whole thing worked.  After that I tried setting the `div` CSS to `'display:none'` (the app required the video to be hidden until requested by the user) which also caused the iFrame API to fail silently (never calling back `'onPlayerReady'`).

So, long story short, when using the YouTube iFrame API to initialize on a `div` that you want to remain hidden until later, use a CSS technique like absolute positioning to push it off screen until you want it later.  Also, found that once the player object is initialized and `'onPlayerReady'` has been called you could turn display on and off all day long and everything would still work as expected.

Comment: That's a good point, and it's also worth mentioning that if you have a visible player, then set `display: none` on the player (or a container), the player is effectively purged by the browser. You would not be able to later set `display: inline` and reuse the same player instance. Moving the player out of the viewport is the answer here, too.

Comment: Please stick to the format. Even if you know the answer to what you're posting, post it as a question _phrased as a question_, and post an answer. (The question web form allows you to post both simultaneously, if you want, so there is no reason to put the answer into the question post.)

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the player conainer empty e.g.

```
<div class="myPlayerContainer"></div>
```

and when you want to show it just append it to container:

```
$('#showVideoBtn').click(function(){
    $('.myPlayerContainer').show().append('~ code of youtube iframe ~');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yotam is right, look at the following:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="toggleYoutube();">show / hide</button>
<div id="youtube"></div>
```

JS ( using jQuery ):

```
var visible = false;
function toggleYoutube() {
    visible = !visible;
    if ( visible ) {
        $("#youtube").append( '<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/cjvIeNt93nc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' );
    } else {
        $("#video").remove();
    }
}
```

See full code at http://jsfiddle.net/wFVhT/2/